# Canvas анимация с помощью координат из массива

Tags: javascript, canvas, анимация

Есть массив в котором хранятся координаты:

```
path.coords = [{ x=77,  y=225}, { x=77,  y=227}, { x=77,  y=228},{ x=77,  y=230}];
```

Всеми силами пытаюсь сделать анимацию, исходя из этих координат, но ни Таймаутами не Интервалами не получается ничего сделать.

Понимаю что нужно перебрать данные из массива и просто нарисовать фигуру > обновить экран > нарисовать фигуру > обновить экран > ....

Вот остановился на переборе данных:

```
context.fillStyle = "red"; 
for(var i=0; i < path.coords.length; i++) { 

  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
  context.fillRect(path.coords[i].x, path.coords[i].y, 10, 10);

 }
```

Всё что нужно, это по очереди выводить фигуры, удаляя старые, тем самым создавая анимацию, но я не могу понять как это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, перепробовал уже всё что мог ...

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код не будет делать анимацию одним только циклом. Даже если предположить, что этот цикл должен выполнятся в каждом фрейме (кадре) - у вас будет рисоваться только один квадрат размером `10` на `10`, если хотите получить фигуру целиком очищать холст нужно вне цикла а не на каждой её итерации, и применяя `context.lineto(path.coords[i].x, path.coords[i].y)` вместо `context.rect(...)` 
чтобы получился контур фигуры (если я вобще правильно вас понял).

Касательно анимации, наиболее общий и простой паттерн есть например, такой:

```
var id = 0;
function render() {      
    for (var i = 0; i < path.coords.length; i++) { 
        context.lineto(path.coords[i].x, path.coords[i].y);
    }

    id = requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function update() {
    // transform your objects position, rotation, scale, attributes etc
}

function animate() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    update();
    render();
}
```

Функция `requestAnimationFrame(callback)` вызывает переданный `callback` через каждые примерно 16мс - это некий аналог `setInterval` но заточенный под анимацию (например на не активной вкладке браузера не тратится процессорное время в отличие от `setInterval`)

> Всё что нужно, это по очереди выводить фигуры, удаляя старые, тем самым создавая анимацию.

Не ясно какая о какой анимаци тут идёт речь. Если вы имеете ввиду афинные преобразования на плоскости то сперва почитайте о [них](http://compgraphics.info/2D/affine_transform.php) - будет полезно в любом случае.
Далее в функции `update` применяете соответствующее преобразование либо при помощи [матричных преобразований](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) либо по координатно. `Canvas API` во всяком случае предоставляет [встроенные методы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations) для преобразования координатной системы (или проще говоря всех точек на канвасе). Но я бы сперва почитал и попробывал реализовать их самому. удачи

Comment: id постоянно равняется нулю, так и должно быть ? В update прописываю context.fillRect(path.coords[i].x,path.coords[i].y,10,10); а когда вызываю animate(); то ничего не происходит.... Конечным результатом должен быть квадрат, который передвигается по экрану следуя координатам из массива с координатами.

Comment: @BimBam в `update` я сказал что делать. Ваш конечный результат нужно было в вопросе сформулировать, чтобы ответы на него были конкретные и более точные.